# SQLServerException: TCP/IP connection to the host has failed

Tags: sql-server

When I am running an Web application, I get an error message

> "The TCP/IP connection to the host,port 1433 has failed. Error:
>   "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties, check that an
>   instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP
>   connections to the port."
>
> The TCP/IP is active and enabled and the TCP port defaults to
>   1433.,But I still get this error message.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: What connection string are you using?  Have you tried using sqlcmd from your web host (if possible) to see if you can reach SQL Server from the web host?  Is your instance of SQL Server running under a non-default name - eg SERVER\instance rather than just SERVER.

Comment: Thanks lan.
SQlServer was unexpectedly shutdown. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 19):

Remove All the TCP Dynamic Ports and Add value of 1433 to all TCP Port
and restart your  SQL Server

### Steps

- Open the Sql Server Configuration Manager (Start -> Programs ->
  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 -> Configuration Tools)
- Expand SQL Server Network Configuration -> [Your Server Instance]
- Double click TCP/IP
- Under Protocol:Ensure Enabled is Yes
- Under IP Addresses:Scroll to the bottom and set the TCP Port under
  IPAll, (1433 by default)
- Find the IP address you want to connect to and set Enabled and Active
  to Yes

Comment: thks so much bro... you saved my day

Comment: If unable to find  SQL Server Configuration Manager, it's will be available on C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager*.msc

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while i was trying connect to MSSQL Server remotely  using JDBC (dbeaver on debian). After a while, I found out that my Windows Firewall configuration was not set up correctly. So maybe this could help you!

Here's how to configure Windows Firewall to allow network traffic that is related to SQL Server and to the SQL Server Browser service. Four exceptions must be configured in Windows Firewall to allow access to SQL Server:

1. Create a port exception for TCP Port 1433:

   1. Open Windows Firewall with Advanced Security
   2. In the left pane, right click on Inbound Rules -> New Rule to get the wizard
   3. What type of rule would you like to create? Select Port
   4. Select TCP and specify port 1433
   5. What action should be taken when a connection matches the specified conditions? Allow the connection
   6. When does the rule apply? Choose all three profiles (Domain, Private & Public)
   7. Name the rule “SQL – TCP 1433″
2. Add a port exception for UDP Port 1434:

   1. Right click on Inbound Rule, click New Rule again and use the following information to create another port
   2. Select Port
   3. Select UDP and specify port 1434
   4. Allow the connection
   5. Choose all three profiles (Domain, Private & Public)
   6. Name the rule “SQL – UDP 1434"
3. Add a program exception for sqlservr.exe:

   1. Click New Rule again and use the following information to create a program
      exception:
   2. Select Program
   3. Click Browse to select ‘sqlservr.exe’ at this location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.*INSTANCE_NAME*\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe where *INSTANCE_NAME* is the name of your SQL instance.
   4. Allow the connection
   5. Choose all three profiles (Domain, Private & Public)
   6. Name the rule "SQL – sqlservr.exe"
4. Add a program exception for sqlbrowser.exe:

   1. Click New Rule again and use the following information to create
      another program exception:
   2. Select Program
   3. Click Browse to select sqlbrowser.exe at this location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\sqlbrowser.exe
   4. Allow the connection
   5. Choose all three profiles (Domain, Private & Public)
   6. Name the rule "SQL - sqlbrowser.exe"

Source: http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried to connect to the Docker image of the SQL Server in my local with DBeaver and I got the same error. However, it turns out it was because the docker image was always down after I tried to run it every time. When I checked the image logs, I found the following:

> ERROR: Unable to set system administrator password: Password
> validation failed. The password does not meet SQL Server password
> policy requirements because it is not complex enough. The password
> must be at least 8 characters long and contain characters from three
> of the following four sets: Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters, Base
> 10 digits, and Symbols..

After I changed the password with the stronger one, I could finally connect with my DBeaver.

A usefule reference: https://medium.com/@joaooliveira889/executing-a-sql-server-docker-container-and-connecting-to-a-net-4b75cae7df32