# [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]...iis notdowngraded right way too

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My website is working perfectly fine on local server but not after i publish it on ftp. After publishing my first view to choose login panel works fine and is working fine but other pages are giving this error given below.
Also someone told me the problem could be because u r using iis express 10 while version 7.5 is available on server.
After i uninstalled version 10 and installed version 7.5 new projects are working fine but not those projects which were made with version 10 of iis express.
I have tried every solution possible on net but nothing worked for his error so am posting this question again...please help

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
```

could it be a reason that am not using membership and so provider and connectionstringname.am using connectionstring but not connectionstringname.

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="UIETPortalDB" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-UIET-Portal-20160707100444.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DefaultConnection.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Connection Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135346/sql-connection-error-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-0x80131904)

Comment: Have you uploaded the all content of the bin directory? It might be missing DLLs.

Comment: all content of bin directory is uploaded.