# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out from Azure VPN

Tags: c#, azure, timeout, azure-vpn

[image]We have a Azure app service which tries to connect to on premise SQL server using 
VPN classic(configured using VNET).

Occasionaly we get the following error :

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()

at Dapper.SqlMapper.d__11`1.MoveNext()

at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)

at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType)

at SiSystems.ClientApp.Web.Domain.Repositories.UserRepository.FindByPrimaryEmail(String username)

at SiSystems.ClientApp.Web.Domain.Repositories.UserRepository.FindByName(String username)

at SiSystems.ClientApp.Web.Auth.UserStore.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0()

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()

at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.d__12.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

at SiSystems.ClientApp.Web.Auth.ApplicationOAuthProvider.d__2.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.d__3f.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)

at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.d__22.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)

at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.d__0.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__0.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__0.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__0.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.d__0.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.d__5.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.d__2.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)

at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar)

at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)

at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Error Number:258,State:0,Class:20

added the image of the log which i got from azure

Answer (score 3):

1-  This could be caused when the tcp protocol is not specified on the db-server-name in the connection string within your application.

second possibility:

2-  go to Sql Server Configuration management->SQL Server network config->protocols for 'servername' and check named pipes is enabled.

3-  Firewall rules:

A port exception for TCP Port 1433. In the New Inbound Rule Wizard dialog, use the following information to create a port exception: Select Port Select TCP and specify port 1433 Allow the connection Choose all three profiles (Domain, Private & Public) Name the rule “SQL – TCP 1433″ A port exception for UDP Port 1434. Click New Rule again and use the following information to create another port exception: Select Port Select UDP and specify port 1434 Allow the connection Choose all three profiles (Domain, Private & Public) Name the rule “SQL – UDP 1434 A program exception for sqlservr.exe. Click New Rule again and use the following information to create a program exception: Select Program Click Browse to select ‘sqlservr.exe’ at this location: [C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe] where is the name of your SQL instance. Allow the connection Choose all three profiles (Domain, Private & Public) Name the rule SQL – sqlservr.exe A program exception for sqlbrowser.exe Click New Rule again and use the following information to create another program exception: Select Program Click Browse to select sqlbrowser.exe at this location: [C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\sqlbrowser.exe]. Allow the connection Choose all three profiles (Domain, Private & Public) Name the rule SQL - sqlbrowser.exe

Refer to: [SQL Connection Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135346/sql-connection-error-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-0x80131904) 
and also: https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/System-Data-SqlClient-SqlException-0x80131904

Comment: Thanks for responding, for me this issue is not coming every time . Its coming only few time only. is there any possibility to come this issue occasionally @Adam Smith-MSFT

Comment: I'd recommend using network watcher to pin point the cause of this issue: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-network-watcher-network-performance-monitoring-and-diagnostics-service-for-azure/ 
You'd need to capture the traffic then verify what issues are happening, if packets are being discarded etc..

Comment: My azure subscription is not allowing to create the network Watcher :( any other option can you suggest ?

Comment: @shamnad could you send me your subscription ID here: azcommunity[AT]microsoft[DOT]com with the precise date and time when this issue occured? I'd like to confirm if none of the resources were down at that time, also, there are several software to monitor traffic, Wireshark is one of them, you could try to capture the traffic when the issue happens, then search by filters to where the issue happens. This needs to be done from within the OS.