# SqlException (0x80131904): The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context

Tags: sql-server, database

Please, help me to solve the problem with my connection to SQL Server.

I got an error:

> SqlException (0x80131904): The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.

I've already tried to follow these recommendations (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/cannot-generate-sspi-context-error), but without any results.

+Additional information:
my connectionStrings file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="redis" connectionString="host=127.0.0.1;db=0;port=6379" />
  <add name="defPackagesWorkingCopyPath" connectionString="%TEMP%\%APPLICATION%\%APPPOOLIDENTITY%\%WORKSPACE%\TerrasoftPackages" />
  <add name="tempDirectoryPath" connectionString="%TEMP%\%APPLICATION%\%APPPOOLIDENTITY%\%WORKSPACE%\" />
  <add name="sourceControlAuthPath" connectionString="%TEMP%\%APPLICATION%\%APPPOOLIDENTITY%\%WORKSPACE%\Svn" />
  <add name="elasticsearchCredentials" connectionString="User=gs-es; Password=DEQpJMfKqUVTWg9wYVgi;" />
  <add name="influx" connectionString="url=http://10.0.7.161:30359; user=; password=; batchIntervalMs=5000" />
  <add name="messageBroker" connectionString="amqp://guest:guest@localhost/BPMonlineSolution" />
  <add name="db" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=BS_BCJ_L_MENU_4118923_0930;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Pooling=true;Max Pool Size=100" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Connection Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135346/sql-connection-error-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-0x80131904)

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: I have also done <Make sure that In SQL Server configuration --> SQL Server Services --> SQL Server Agent is enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager>

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: why do you need sspi over localhost. You should be able to use standard Integrated Security=True

Comment: I've just tried to change "SSPI" to "True" and got the same result.

Comment: The connection string doesn't have a username, so that means it is connecting using "integrated authentication". It looks like the user identity running your code is not recognized by the SQL server instance. Probably you are not part of a domain or are not using a domain account to run it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :
Integrated Security=False

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34866608)